# webpage snapshot in dcef3

Tags: delphi, chromium, snapshot

I've tried the TChromiumOSR and TPaintbox32,it works fine. However, but not all the screenshot of webpage, only the part.So maybe I need the width and the height of the webpage,but I can't find a way to get it.This is my method of solving the problem,could you give me the solution or is there any faster ways?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) inside a your chromium instance. The user could choose a part of a [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and our application made the screenshot and stored it somewhere on the disk. The advantage with this approach is, that you allways get the hole page and not just with what you see. You could use the `OnLoadEnd` event, to put your javascript inside the page your are loading and then make the screenshot and save it somewhere. I'm sorry I cant provide any sourcecode, I dont have access to this project any more. The downside of this approach is, that you need some decent javascript skills, to pull this one off.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It maybe useful but I need all screenshot not the part.I have succeed to get all screenshot of the webpage.I use JS to get the width and height of the webpage,and then use the `OnPaint` event.